# Is there any way to add an HTTP Header to every IE request on a computer?

Tags: windows, windows-7, powershell, batch-file, windows-registry

I would like to add a custom HTTP Header to every Internet Explorer request on a computer (or every browser request). I don't know if this is possible whatsoever, if you have heard of anyway to accomplish such a task, could you please point me in a general direction?

I've thought about opening IE with a PowerShell wrapper, or editing the registry but can't find out if headers can be modified that way. I'm open to whatever options may be available but I'm coming up short in a way to achieve this. Thank you!

I apologize if this is the wrong place for this question and I appreciate any guidance or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think that this is possible without additional software.

in general you may use squid proxy for this purpose. 
but be aware that modification of http headers on a proxy is violating the http standard.

Comment: Thanks!  I am actually trying to modify the x-ms-proxy header for ADFS to consume.  But the client isn't using Web Application Proxy, so that header isn't injected.

Comment: I found Customize user agent string in the Internet Explorer section of the Group Policy Managment Editor.  I was hoping I had other options.